# Codeigniter Database Connectivity

Tags: codeigniter

I m getting an error message on Codeigniter while I m trying to fetch data from the database on line number 10,12,14

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>view</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>

    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Welcome to my view page!</h1>
        <br/>
        <?php echo $title; ?>
        <br/>
        <?php echo $test1; ?>
        <br/>
        <?php echo $model_data; ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

ERROR is shown after running

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLdAR.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . Please share the error message in your post.

Comment: show me your controller code

Answer (score 2):

You cant get data this way. I assume you got values from database in your **model** and pass it to this **view** .  Lets say your array name is **$result**.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>view</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>

    </head>
    <body>
      <?php 
         foreach($result as $values){
           $title = $values->title;
           $test1 = $values->test1;
         }
       ?>
        <h1>Welcome to my view page!</h1>
        <br/>
        <?php echo $title; ?>
        <br/>
        <?php echo $test1; ?>
        <br/>
    </body>
</html>
```